# Rails doesn't map my url correctly with url_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newbie in the Rails, but I can't figure this out.

```
Rails maps url_for(:controller => 'login', :action => 'check')
```

to

```
"/assets?action=check&amp;controller=login"
```

It should be mapped to /en/login/check (coming from /en/login/index)

My routes.rb:

```
MyApplication::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|de/ do
    resources :login do
      get 'index', :on => :member
      get 'check', :on => :member
    end

  end

  match ':locale/:controller/:action/:id'
  match ':controller/:action/:id'
  match ':locale/:controller/:action/:id.:format'
  match ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

  root :to => 'main#index'
end
```

I'll read some more about routing, but I'm really confused where /assets comes from and why it's not mapped correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the :locale in the url_for helper, else the router won't actually find a match.

```
url_for(locale: 'en', controller: 'login', action: 'index')
```

Comment: Can't it defer that from the current url (being en/login/check)? + Can you configure rails to throw an error if it doesn't find a match?

Comment: The current url?  You mean can't it tell if the words are in english or german?  I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Mmm, I know it seems a dumn question, but I can't imagine needing to specify in all url_for statements which language is being used.

Comment: Not sure what the assets business is all about (something going on with a gem, maybe?) but one thing you want to do is change `get :check, :on => :member` to `get :check, :on => :collection`. Otherwise it expects an `:id`.

Comment: I added def default_url_options(options={}) to application_controller, which adds the locale to al my urls. Together with :collection, things now work. Thx.

Comment: Another thing I was wondering, why isn't login_check_path working? I'm getting an error from rails saying undefined local variable or method `login_check_path'

Comment: Run `rake routes` to see what is being generated. The leftmost column shows you your named routes (without _path).